# How do I get VS11.0 common tools?

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2013

I have a build failing due to an attempt to call the following "%VS110COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"

I know this is failing because I do not have a VS11.0 folder or the subsequent common tools which is required.  I am currently running VS2013, my question is how do I get the VS11.0 folder and common tools?  I have been unable to find it via VS or MS websites.

I do not wish to hack it and just make it point to my vs12.0 common tools folder as frankly I do not know what implications, if any, that brings.

Thank you

Comment: That refers to a VS2012 folder.  So sure, the environment variable isn't going to be set and total fail whale if you don't have VS2012 installed.  Editing it to VS120COMNTOOLS is the obvious approach.

Comment: thank you for your comment Hans, I understand that.  The issue is how do I get it installed given I already have a newer version?  If not possible, is editing and pointing to VS120 a clean solution, surely there are issues/downsides to this?

Comment: Building projects with VS2012 has a *lot* more downfalls, mixing compiler versions is a recipe for DLL and linking trouble.  The C++11 changes are a heavy problem multiplier.  Installing multiple VS versions is not a problem.  No idea why you are not just trying this.  Ask for support from the project owner.

Comment: thank you Hans, I previously attempted to install VS2012 and it failed due to having a more recent version, I didn't want to uninstall and re-install in order.  Is there no simpler way to get just what I need?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that ends up stuck in the same position as me, Hans Passant was indeed correct that Visual Studio 12 was needed.  As I mentioned in the comments, I had previously tried to do this and it had failed.  For me I needed to remove some of the more recent MS Visual C++ redistributables before it would allow Visual Studio 12 to install.  Hope that helps somebody out there and thank you Hans for the pointer in the right direction